# how to set a radio button value in protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm new to Protractor, I'm trying to set the radio button value using Protractor. I searched over the internet and the SO for the answers which went vain.

**html:**

```
<md-radio-group
            id="radiogrp1"
            name="radiogrp1"
            ng-model="application.myRadioGrp"                
            required>
        <md-radio-button value="N" aria-label="No">No</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="Y" aria-label="Yes">Yes</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="M" aria-label="Maybe">May</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

From the above html file, I tried to set No/Yes/Maybe while executing in my jasmine it() with some Protractor code like shown below:

```
element.all(by.id('radiogrp1)).get(0).click();
```

For this above code it default accepts yes alone. I want specifically set any value of radio group i.e., child(md-radio-button) like Yes/No/Maybe of parent(md-radio-grp). I tried in many ways like bind, map etc., but nothing helped really. Looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting ;)
https://sathyalog.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-set-a-radio-button-value-in-protractor/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
element(by.id('radiogrp1')).all(by.tagName('md-radio-button')).get(0).click();
```