# Protractor - select a radio from unknown group

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I am testing a survery application in which each page has 10 questions - each question has 5 options (radio buttons). For testing purpose i need to select some choice, it can be first or last - does not really matter.  I would not know the name of the radio buttons as it is going to be completely random for each question.

My logic was get to the names for all the radio buttons first and then select last radio from the group.

```
    var radioNames = {};
    $$("input[type=radio]").filter(function(elem,index){
        elem.getAttribute("name").then(function(name){
            radioNames[name] = true;
        });
    }).then(function(){
        for (name in radioNames){
            $$("input[name='" + name + "']").last().click();
        }
    })
```

It works fine. My question: Is there any better logic, with less coding to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866054/how-to-set-a-radio-button-value-in-protractor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) would be a more suitable choice:

```
$$("input[type=radio]").map(function(elem) {
    return elem.getAttribute("name");
}).then(function(radioNames) {
    for (name in radioNames) {
        $$("input[name='" + name + "']").last().click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks @alecxe